How to deal with missing values in a panel survey (for Propensity score matching analysis)
I would like to know what is the recommended method for data imputation for propensity score matching in panel survey data. This survey has 4 waves and I am examining the treatment effect between the 2nd and 3rd wave. I have missing values in the covariates (wave 2) as well as treatment and outcome (wave 3). What is the appropriate way to impute the data if the missing values are partly due to participation in a particular wave of the survey (some respondents did not respond in that wave) and at the same time I have some observations from other waves of the survey (this is a survey of 4 waves in total)?
Alternatively, should this be done at all? I have also come across the view that if there are missing values in the outcome and treatment, one should not impute or use PSM and rather use other methods (regressions controlling for covariates, etc.). Thank you in advance for your reply.
